# How to overwrite the default behaviour of the onchange event of a FilteringSelect dojo widget?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have the following code:

```
dijit.byId('patient').onchange(function(event){
      var term=dijit.byId('patient').get('value');                                                             
      patientList.url = ".calendar/search-patient?term="+term;
      patientList.close();                                  
})
```

What I am trying to do is to overwrite the default behaviour of the "onchange" event of a FilteringSelect dojo widget. The problem is that I get the error: "*This deferred has already been resolved*".

How could I overwrite the default behaviour of the "onchange" event? Thank you

Comment: Not familiar with this framework, but try adding `return false;` as well.

Comment: I have tried that too. Same error. I think that, once it sees the "onchange" event for that element, it trows the error, so it doesn't reach at the preventDefault() point.

Comment: If you add `alert('debug');` do you see it at all?

Comment: So you asked the wrong question.. it should be "How to overwrite the default behaviour of the `onchange` event of a FilteringSelect dojo widget?"

Comment: I thought that this is what preventDefault does... but yes, that's what I want to do

Comment: The `preventDefault()` only prevent the event from "streaming upwards" for example when you run your own code when clicking a link, it will prevent the browser from redirecting to the link target.

Comment: I have changed the title, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dijit.byId` function returns a dijit object, and I don't think it has a member function `onchange` that takes a function as parameter.

Try doing this instead:

```
dojo.connect(dijit.byId("patient"), "onChange", function(value)
{
    patientList.url = ".calendar/search-patient?term=" + value;
    patientList.close();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This way I don't get the error but I don't think it listen to the event (or it doesn't overwrite the event) of the element because I don't get any response (I have tried with an alert but nothing).

Comment: @sica07 That's weird. Are you sure you are using `onChange` and not `onchange` (incorrect caps)? Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D7Xym/

Comment: onchange was the problem. Stupid me. Now it works! Thanks a lot!